# jQuery Mobile and MVC URL debarkles?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url, mobile

Anyone who has started mixing the two must have come up with some interesting results, I certainly have and the current one is.

I have a Drop Down List that auto submits to a new page and sends over the id value to the controller for processing. It works fine the first time but if I hit a back button (hardware,  jQuery, back or ActionLink ) and try again, unless I hit refresh it tries to tack an extra /id value on the end of the URL string. The more times I try the more it tacks, until I hit refresh and then it works. E.g..

www.mysite.com  clicks through to www.mysite.com/Home/resultpage/2 it works but when I click back to www.mysite.com and select again, I get an error 404 because it’s looking for www.mysite.com/Home.resultpage/2/4 then if I select again I get  www.mysite.com/Home.resultpage/2/4/5 and so on until I refresh and it works again, once.

Can I do anything about that, even if it’s a hack!

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: Can you include some code so we can get an idea of why it might not be working !

Comment: There is not really anything to show, it works fine outside of jQuery Mobile but not inside it, like lots of things I’ve found!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JQuery mobile requesting via ajax and not having the `data-url` to correct the url.

[jQuery Mobile/MVC: Getting the browser URL to change with RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824243/jquery-mobile-mvc-getting-the-browser-url-to-change-with-redirecttoaction)