# Controller doesn't redirect after form submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.net MVC and I am struggling to make this work at the moment. I have a controller method called `Add`, it looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    // check user is authenticated
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

//
// POST: /Home/Add

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(string title, string description, string priority, string color, FormCollection collection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // create instance of todo object
        todo obj = new todo();

        try
        {
            // gather fields
            obj.priority = Convert.ToInt32(priority);
            obj.color = Convert.ToInt32(color);
            obj.title = title;
            obj.description = description;

            todosDataContext objLinq = new todosDataContext();

            // get the users id, convert to string and store it
            var userid = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            obj.userid = userid.ToString();

            // save
            objLinq.todos.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
            objLinq.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(obj);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

If data is sent via POST to the method, it should add the data to the database. That is working fine and everything is added correctly. However, the `RedirectToAction` is not firing, and the application gets stuck at `/Home/Add`, when it should redirect to `/Home/Index`. The view loads however, so it shows `/Home/Index` but the URL says `/Home/Add`.

Here is a copy of the partial view that contains the form:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<todo_moble_oauth.Models.todo>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

<fieldset>

    <h3>Title:</h3>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" name="title" />
    </div>

    <h3>Description:</h3>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" name="description" />
    </div>

    <h3>Priority:</h3>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select name="priority">
            <option value="1">Low</option>
            <option value="2">Medium</option>
            <option value="3">High</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <h3>Color:</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="radio-choice-1" value="0" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">None</label>

            <input type="radio" name="color" id="radio-choice-2" value="1"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Red</label>

            <input type="radio" name="color" id="radio-choice-3" value="2"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Blue</label>

            <input type="radio" name="color" id="radio-choice-4" value="3"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Yellow</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

So data is being sent to the database and stored, however the redirect is broken.

Comment: It throws an exception then. Put a breakpoint inside your catch block.

Comment: Yes, it appears you have an exception and are executing your catch block `return View(obj);`

Comment: It is executing fine, data is saved, and the redirect is being performed, the address url doesn't change which messes up the application, however it loads the view Index().

Comment: Could it be something to do with jQuery mobile? I'm using it as well, but am new to the framework

Comment: Then I misunderstood *"However, the `RedirectToAction` is not firing"*

Comment: Yes, that was posted before I used a breakpoint to determine it was firing.. turns out the issue is with jQuery mobile, after doing some searching using it as a reference I found this thread which fixed my error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824243/jquery-mobile-mvc-getting-the-browser-url-to-change-with-redirecttoaction

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with jQuery mobile, this threads solution resolved the issue for me:

[jQuery Mobile/MVC: Getting the browser URL to change with RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824243/jquery-mobile-mvc-getting-the-browser-url-to-change-with-redirecttoaction)