# Navigates of page programmatically but address bar URL doesn't changes

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I am using `J-Query Mobile` and `AngularJS` and on the pressing link i want navigate user to different page it navigates but url address in    address bar doesn't change how to solve this issue. I ma using the single page structure

HTML Part

```
<a href="" ng-controller="addFoodToLog" ng-click="go()" data-role="button">Add To Log</a>
```

JS Part

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('addFoodToLog',function($scope){
  $scope.go = function() {
    //Here Selected Food Bump In Food Log
    alert("Successfully Add In Your Log");
    $.mobile.changePage('index.html#foodscreen');
  }
});
```

Comment: Somebody asked it before <br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824243/jquery-mobile-mvc-getting-the-browser-url-to-change-with-redirecttoaction
You have to disable mobile ajax. look at the link.

Comment: where i disable mobile ajax

Comment: @Dvir
i added like this but no effects
<a href="" data-ajax="false" ng-controller="addFoodToLog" ng-click="go()" data-role="button">Add To Log</a>

Comment: You move from page1.html to page2.html? Or you navigate within the same index.html from #page1 to #page2? If the latter, `$.mobile.changePage('#foodscreen', { changeHash: true });`.

Comment: @Omar i have just index page its single page structure
`$.mobile.changePage('#foodscreen', { changeHash: true });`
but this not help same issue

Comment: Ok, try `$(window).hashchange();` after `$.mobile.changePage('#foodscreen', { changeHash: true });`.

Comment: @Omar no effects after added. i did like that
`myApp.controller('addFoodToLog',function($scope){
  $scope.go = function() {
    //Here Selected Food Bump In Food Log
    alert("Successfully Add In Your Log");
    $.mobile.changePage('#foodscreen', { changeHash: true });
    $(window).hashchange();
  }
});`

Comment: Why not use the Angular router?

Comment: @BrianGenisio how?
what changes are require what should write instead of `$.mobile.changePage('#foodscreen', { changeHash: true }); `

Comment: Checkout `$route` and `$location` in Angular.js documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location.  You can also watch the Angular routing story in http://egghead.io episodes 29-33.  A more full-featured router replacement is the AngularUI UI-Router.  These systems help you manage your Angular application states much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue
If you use `Angular-JS`, `JQuery Mobile` and also `Angular JQM Adopter` then you can achieve your requirement by change your code from

```
myApp.controller('addFoodToLog',function($scope){
    $scope.go = function() {
    //Here Selected Food Bump In Food Log
    alert("Successfully Add In Your Log");
    $.mobile.changePage('index.html#foodscreen');
    }
});
```

To this

```
myApp.controller('addFoodToLog',function($scope,$location){
    $scope.go = function() {
    //Here Selected Food Bump In Food Log
    alert("Successfully Add In Your Log");
    $location.hash('foodscreen');
  }
});
```